_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories: I need to use library FreeSimpleGUI without problems in Python
I am using Python 3.13, and I have installed FreeSimpleGUI library, because I need it for working with some of their functions.
I have run the following code: "import FreeSimpleGUI" in a .py file and I have got an error.
You can see the error below. I think there is a problem with a file called init.cl. Could you help me with this issue? I would like to use the library FreeSimpleGUI without problems.
Thanks in advance!
C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\todo_app\.venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\todo_app\gui.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\todo_app\gui.py", line 1, in <module>
    import FreeSimpleGUI
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\todo_app\.venv\Lib\site-packages\FreeSimpleGUI\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    tclversion_detailed = tkinter.Tcl().eval('info patchlevel')
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2572, in Tcl
    return Tk(screenName, baseName, className, useTk)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2459, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories: 
    C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python313/lib/tcl8.6 C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/todo_app/.venv/lib/tcl8.6 C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/todo_app/lib/tcl8.6 C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/todo_app/.venv/library C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/todo_app/library C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/todo_app/tcl8.6.14/library C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/tcl8.6.14/library



This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.


Process finished with exit code 1

